# No internal speaker sound on linux with lenovo legion 7i (ALC287) only when jack is connected

Tags: linux, audio, lenovo-laptop, sound-card

I've been trying different options to try to get sound working on the internal speakers of my lenovo legion 7i on linux.

A few things to consider:

Sound card is recognized (screenshot will be shown below) inxi and lspci are showing the correct sound card. The soundcard is the internal on the laptop (ALC287)

Alsamixer is not showing anything as muted whatsoever

There is sound activity being displayed in pavucontrol.

I've tried turning HDMI off just in case, no change

Tried adding different options in alsa conf files (auto, basic, etc)
without success

when connecting the headphones through the audio jack all works as expected

Tried with a fairly new kernels (at the moment 5.7.9)

[aplay command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wzrb.png)

[lspci and inxi commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TcFS.png)

[alsamixer with nothing muted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY8rc.png)

Hope that someone can give me a hand with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Had the same issue... Found this linux kernel issue report https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208555